# Download files with custom filenames in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I put `download.default_directory` property to `prefs` variable with path to directory where files should be saved after downloading. `download.prompt_for_download` is set to `true` in `prefs`, but dialog doesn't appear. I don't know, how to set custom filenames, because downloads are started automatically.

Comment: Do you have a solution for changing the name in the download prompt? I ask because Selenium by itself cannot modify that text, so you'll need something outside of Selenium also running. I just want you to know the next obstacle before trying to fix this. It may be easier to download the file via its default name then use whatever language you're using to rename it on the drive.

Comment: @MivaScott : Yes, I can use `Robot` for this purpose, if dialog window is opened. It should get its name, when downloaded, because it would be a unique identifier for the file.

Comment: `browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force` is true, but it doesn't show dialog.